# Bitnami Review Board is not working with SVN in Windows

Tags: python, windows, svn, review-board, pysvn

I am confusing if Bitnami Review Board is working with SVN repository. I think it should work, as i saw this https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/admin/configuration/repositories/subversion/. But when I tried to add a svn repository, I cannot find the Subversion option under the "Repository type".

Is there anyone could help me have a look if my configuration is incorrect?

Environment:

- System: Windows 10, 64 bit
- Review Board version: 2.5.16
- Python version: 2.7.13
- Python directory: C:\Bitnami\reviewboard\python
- SVN version: 1.8.17 (r1770682)
- SVN directory: C:\Bitnami\reviewboard\svn
- PySVN version: py27-pysvn-svn1816-1.9.3-1884-Win32
- PySVN directory:
  C:\Bitnami\reviewboard\python\Lib\site-packages\pysvn

I tried to test if the pySVN is detected by Python by

> ">>> import pysvn"

it works without any error.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that we do not bundle subversion in the Windows stack. You may be able no make it work if you manually try to install subversion and the python libraries, but that is something we do not support. If you want to use subversion + Reviewboard in a Windows server, the closest thing we can recommend you is our Virtual Machine: https://bitnami.com/stack/reviewboard/virtual-machine

The answer is from [Bitnami's Javier J. Salmerón](https://community.bitnami.com/t/reviewboard-windows-and-subversion-integration-issue/53637)